# Get filename from QFile?

Tags: qt, qt4

eg:

```
QFile f("/home/umanga/Desktop/image.jpg");
```

How I get only the filename - "image.jpg"?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Use a [`QFileInfo`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html#fileName) to strip out the path (if any):

```
QFileInfo fileInfo(f.fileName());
QString filename(fileInfo.fileName());
```

Comment: You can make this even shorter by giving the QFile as a parameter to the QFileInfo constructor: `QFileInfo fileInfo(f);`

Comment: If the file does not exist this will fail.

Answer (score 16):

One approach, not necessarily the best: from a `QFile`, you can get the file specification with [`QFile::fileName()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qfile.html#fileName):

```
QFile f("/home/umanga/Desktop/image.jpg");
QString str = f.fileName();
```

then you can just use the string features like [`QString::split`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qstring.html#split):

```
QStringList parts = str.split("/");
QString lastBit = parts.at(parts.size()-1);
```

Comment: QString section is more situable:

Comment: QString lastBit = str.section("/", -1, -1);

Comment: @Kamil, you should leave that as an answer rather than a comment, then I'll upvote it :-)

Comment: @bat_ventzi, why do you believe it won't work for something like `../../a/b/c`? That would still split correctly and give you `c`.

Comment: Actually you are right @paxdiablo. I don't know why I've commented that way. :) Should I remove the comment?

Comment: @bat_ventzi, it's up to you. I'll keep an eye on it for a while and, if you do, I'll also delete mine. Or you can leave it there as commentary, I'm sure SO won't miss a few bytes here and there ;-)

Comment: The `split` approach relies on the path separator being `/`. On some systems this won't work.

Answer (score 11):

just in addition: to seperate filename and file path having `QFile f`

```
QString path = f.fileName();
QString file = path.section("/",-1,-1);
QString dir = path.section("/",0,-2);
```

you don't need to create an additional fileInfo.

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
bool utes::pathsplit(QString source,QString *path,QString *filename)
{
QString fn;
int index;
    if (source == "") return(false);
    fn = source.section("/", -1, -1);
    if (fn == "") return(false);
    index = source.indexOf(fn);
    if (index == -1) return(false);
    *path = source.mid(0,index);
    *filename = fn;
    return(true);
}
```

Comment: Smart, but for me it seems like a long U turn.
+1 Because i had to search for the meaning of **QString::section()** and **QString::mid()**, i didn't knew about them